# Ubuntu slow to wake up from sleep

Tags: suspend, login-screen, macosx, macbook-air

So, I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my 2014 Macbook Air 13inch (no dual boot). When I close the lid, the apple logo is still lit and the screen stays on. Because of this I usually press command L (super L) and then the computer will sleep. When I press a key to wake it afer, sometimes it wakes immediately but most of the times I have to wait around thirty seconds for the screen to turn on. Why?!?

Comment: What have you done to debug the issue yourself? What does the syslog say? Have you checked which packages are needed? Did you do anything?

Comment: It's difficult to know what's going on without a bit more information. Blank screens always make me think it's an nVidia problem. Does your Macbook have nVidia graphics? What processor does it have? Go into Suspend and then resume and open a terminal and type **less /var/log/kern.log** (use pageup and pagedown to scroll through the entries) see if there are any differences in behaviour between a 'good' suspend and a 'slow' resume. Suspend entries start with **PM: suspend entry (deep)**. Read through and see if there are some clues as to why it's good sometimes and bad other times

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on my Dell Precision 7520 since upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04.

Upgrading the kernel from 4.15.something to 4.20.10 with Ukuu seems to fix it. Instant resume after testing it by going back to bed for an hour having closed the lid and watched the lights go out.